# identityServer4 javascript cros request

Tags: javascript, identityserver4

i use identityServer4 and configure a simple client:

```
    public static IEnumerable<Client> Clients =>
        new List<Client>
        {
            new Client
            {
                ClientId="client",
                AllowedGrantTypes =GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,
                ClientSecrets={
                new Secret("test".Sha256())
                },
                AllowedCorsOrigins = {
                    "http://192.168.0.105:8080",
                    "http://localhost:5001"
                },
                AllowedScopes={ "api1"}
            }
        };
}
```

and i send a javascript ajax request:

```
  var url = "http://localhost:5001/test/get";
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", url);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  };
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer mytoken");
  xhr.send();
```

but preflight returns 401:
[view img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j5LkQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Is the API in the same application as IdentityServer?

The AllowedCorsOrigins you set in the client configuration is only applied for CORS request to IdentityServer itself. If you have your own API, you need to set CORS yourself.

See [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-3.1)